# How to configure SQLAlchemy session.flush() periodically

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, flush

Is there a way that when creating a session object, I could configure it to execute flush() periodically?

The reason I need this feature is because under the scope of a session, it is running a non-short background job in memory. I want the program to update the progress of the job with DB periodically using flush(), so that my client can query the progress from DB.

Currently, my solution is using another thread that periodically executes session.flush().

Thanks!

Comment: You should be calling `commit()` to let other clients see your changes; the fact that `flush()` also works is a side effect of the isolation level you are using. To achieve your goal, whenever you want to report the progress in your job, update your model and commit; there's no need for a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the `commit()`. After some experimenting, I find that the transaction level in my session is REPEATABLE READ, but my clients could still read uncommitted updates. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: You either have `autoflush` on and are triggering the autoflush, or `autocommit` on.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call `session.flush()` again and again in your code. By default in SqlAlchmey `autoflush` is set to True. Which means any update, delete, insert operations are already added to transeaction for commit. So any query to DB always get the latest data as i't unit of work pattern that even if a select query is fired the uncommiteed changes should be commited first.

```
In [8]: session.autoflush
Out[8]: True

In [9]: session.autocommit
Out[9]: False
```

Comment: So autoflush() triggers session.flush(). Before sesson.flush() is triggered, any update, delete, insert operations will not be added transaction.